# utl_smtp how to handle rejection emails from wrong email address

Tags: plsql

I am wring script to send email from Oracle DB by PL SQL but if email address I receive mail to "from" sender, but I want to change this email to other email.

Comment: I might be too little information, please post your code

Comment: And an example would also be helpful. Please review [ask].

Comment: example, if my email is mohamed_mohamed_1981@hotmail.com but I enter in the email mohamed_mohamed_198111111@hotmail.com (this email is not exist at all) or mohamed_mohamed_1981@hotm.com and this host is not exist "hotm", so I will have rejection and my sender is no-repy@company.com but I need to receive mail on support@company.com, so how I configure it in UTL_SMTP